# My website not working (ERROR) in IE

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, autocomplete, jsonp

Have a look at one of my websites: [moskah.com](http://moskah.com/)

The problem is that it doesn't function properly in IE as it is in all other browsers.

First of all I'm getting an error that 'jquery.ui.min.js' is not supported. When I type something I get a second error which is telling me 'access denied for jquer.min etc'.

I have spend many hours trying to figure this out but in the end I really have no idea what is going on. When I test offline it actually does work in IE, but online it doesn't. I need to know what is going on so I can focus on that issue.

Comment: What is the version of jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried with a newer version of jQuery? I have a feeling that 1.6.1+ addressed the issue cross domain spoofing.. Since you are querying query.yahooapis.com that may or may not be the issue. IE is a bit more finicky about this.

Comment: Also - in your source - you do not have your bound jquery events inside $(document).ready() function. Why do you not have them inside there?

Comment: @Barry Chapman The script Im using does not function with jquery 1.6 It only works with 1.4 (I mean the live search not the autocomplete ajax request)

Comment: Then you will need to use 1.7x version of jQuery UI as the version of jQuery you are using does not support delegate()

Comment: @Barry Chapman Im using 1.8 for the ui...Which is 'better' than 1.7 Or do you mean the jquery and not the ui??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that method 'delegate' is not supported by jQuery 1.4.1.
You have to update jQuery at least to the version 1.5.1.

Comment: Your right, its seems to take care of the problem but now my other script doesn't work (it only seems to work with 1.4) Well I guess that is another story:) Thanks.